# No rails found in sdk intellij

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I set up a rails project, it all works fine, but I can't get it running through IntelliJ.

I have rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.2.0 (had 2.3.0 and I've read that it may not be supported by IntelliJ). I'm using vagrant. In my configuration I have:

Ruby SDK: Use other SDK: Remote:ruby-2.2.0-p0 (vagrant:\C:\some-app\usr\local\rvm\rubies\ruby-2.2.0\bin\ruby)

The following commands in vagrant give me:

```
which ruby -> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby

which rails -> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails
```

I keep getting the No Rails found in SDK error. How can I solve this? I did not find anything that works for me.

Comment: dnt never post images, update yr post.

Comment: What's the problem with images? (I'll update it)

Comment: Don't post the code/errors as images because they are a bit unreadable and they are unable to copy.

Comment: Ok, sorry did not know

Comment: Are you using JetBrains' Intellij *Idea*?  As you know, but other people might not, that is a primarily Java IDE. Its Ruby support, even with the plugin, is nowhere near as good as that of RubyMine, the JetBrains IDE made specifically for Ruby.  I use RubyMine as my primary editing environment and it works great.  If there's any way you can get RubyMine I highly recommend it.

Comment: same problem, solved?

Comment: That comment about intellij vs ruby mines is distinctly at odds with what JetBrains say. Yes, there may be a slight delay in feature sets but the ruby plugin provides ruby mine functionality.